# $S^4\setminus S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^4 \setminus\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that $S^4\setminus S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^4 \setminus\Bbb{R}^2$, with $\Bbb{R}^2 = \{(x,y,0,0):x,y\in\Bbb{R}\}\subseteq\Bbb{R}^4$ and $S^2 = \{(x,y,z,0):x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$.

Now, the model solution states that the homeomorphism holds by stereographic projection from a point in $S^2$.

To be a model solution, it seems bold to me. I would have not felt confident enough to just state that in an exam. Even though we are talking about 4 dimensions, is there any way to have a clearer intuition about this fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that the stereographic projection is a homeomorphism between a sphere (of any dimension) minus one point and the Euclidean space of same dimension. Now, if you do the stereographic projection defined in $\Bbb S^4$ minus the point $(1,0,0,0)$ in $\Bbb S^2$, this will give a homeomorphism between that and $\Bbb R^4$. If you restrict that to $\Bbb S^4\setminus \Bbb S^2$, the points you will remove from the image of the projection seem to be precisely the $\Bbb R^2$ corresponding to $\Bbb S^2$ under the "same" projection (realized in the hyperplane $\Bbb R^3\times \{0\}$). Thus it restricts to $\Bbb S^4\setminus \Bbb S^2\cong \Bbb R^4\setminus \Bbb R^2$.

---

For completeness, let $N \in \Bbb S^n$ be a point. For any $p\in \Bbb S^n$, consider the ray starting at $N$ and passing through $p$. Such a line will cross the hyperplane $N^\perp$ in exactly one point ${\rm St}_N(p)$. This defines a homeomorphism between $\Bbb S^n\setminus\{N\}$ and $N^\perp$, whose inverse is constructed as follows: given $x\in N^\perp$, consider the line passing through $x$ and $N$. This will cross $\Bbb S^n$ in two distinct points. One is $N$ itself -- call the other one ${\rm St}_N^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for both the more pictorial description and the more rigorous construction! 
Just one thing about the hyperplane $N^\perp$: is the only condition on it that it does not contain $N$? So that it could even intersect $S^n$?

Comment: Well, $N$ is a point on the sphere and $N^\perp$ is a plane passing through the origin. Say you take $p \in \Bbb S^n$ and parametrize the line passing through $N$ and $p$ by $r(t) = N + t(p-N)$. Then $0 = \langle r(t), N\rangle = 1 + t(\langle p,N\rangle - 1)$ implies that $t = 1/(1-\langle p,N\rangle)$. Meaning that $${\rm St}_N(p) = N + \frac{p-N}{1-\langle p,N\rangle}.$$You do a similar thing to find ${\rm St}^{-1}_N(x)$ using the condition $\|r(t)\|^2=1$, and this second degree equation for $t$ has two solutions. One gives the point $N$, and the other gives ${\rm St}_N^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: This projection is a map ${\rm St}_N\colon \Bbb S^n\setminus \{N\} \to N^\perp$. There is no way to extend it to $\Bbb S^n$. Roughly, we would send $N$ to "infinity" (i.e., $\lim_{p \to N} {\rm St}_N(p)$ does not exist).

Comment: Keeping in mind the 3-dimensional case makes this more readable, thank you again!